# Triangle inequality for functions.

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality, integral-inequality

Is the triangle inequality also true for functions? if so why? my confusion comes from that sup of the sum of two sets is different from supremum of the sum of 2 functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triangle inequality is a property of a normed vector space (by definition). So you can't ask this question about "functions" in general, but about a particular choice of function space and candidate norm. The very common $L^p$ spaces do satisfy the triangle inequality for $p > 1$, including the supremum case $p=\infty$ (this is Minkowski's inequality.)

Comment: I meant $C[a,b]$ space with $\|f\| _{1} =\int_{a}^{b} |f|.$

Comment: I think the given norm is the $L^1$ norm because my functions are Lebegue integrable because they are Riemann integrable ... am I correct?